# How to handle working folder when Laravel in WSL2 docker environment point to variable folder instead of original project folder?

Tags: php, laravel, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

When I was working on my website using wsl2's environment (using `./vendor/bin/sail up`), some helper such as `public_path()` and `storage_path()` are not pointed to the original project folder, below are the output when dump them with `dump()`.

```php
Route::get('/', function () {
    dump(public_path());
    dump(storage_path());
});
```

```
^ "/var/www/html/public"
^ "/var/www/html/storage"
```

This makes me have some problems when dealing with the file uploading function.

Some solutions I tried:

1. Recreate a brand new laravel project and test it out with the `public_path()` and `storage_path()`.
2. Try it in other device.

Kinda weird when come to the storage link

```
$ php artisan storage:link

The [/home/ahming/example-app/public/storage] link has been connected to [/home/ahming/example-app/storage/app/public].
The links have been created.
```

Also it works on the tinker

```
$ php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.11.5 (PHP 8.1.7 - cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> public_path()
=> "/home/ahming/example-app/public"
```

Edit:

Just find out that using `php artisan serve` do not have the problem on returning wrong directory, so the problem might be focus on the docker.

When using the `sail` on [running the tinker command](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sail#executing-artisan-commands), it also returned the same result:

```
$ ./vendor/bin/sail artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.11.5 (PHP 8.1.7 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> public_path()
=> "/var/www/html/public"
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
# For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.1
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.1/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
            - '${HMR_PORT:-8080}:8080'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - 'sail-mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
            - './vendor/laravel/sail/database/mysql/create-testing-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sh'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    phpmyadmin:
        image: 'phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin'
        links:
            - mysql:mysql
        ports:
            - '8000:80'
        environment:
            MYSQL_USERNAME: "${DB_USERNAME}"
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${DB_PASSWORD}"
            PMA_HOST: mysql
        networks:
            - sail
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sail-mysql:
        driver: local
```

Comment: What is the issue with `public_path()` returning `"/var/www/html/public"` is that path inaccessible? the path is dependent on the environment. Please add more details about your issue as being *"some problems when dealing with the file uploading function"*.

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you use `php artisan serve` ?

Comment: @N69S The path should be returned as `/home/ahming/example-app/public` which means that whenever I call it in my controller or any other places, definitely will cause some problems on file uploading function or other functions which relating on using the `public_path()` helper function, so that's why I'm asking about why this happen in wsl environment.

Comment: @apokryfos I tested, and found out that `php artisan server` return the correct directory.

Comment: What is showing inside of the config/filesystems.php file under disks?

Comment: @Yeak Since I freshly generate the project, that file is still remain in default settings, but it should not be related to this problem right? Inside `config/filesystems.php` also uses the `public_path()` and `storage_path()`, in this case, they are also returning the wrong directory when I trying to use them for file uploading etc. If not mistaken, it is related to the docker environment.

Comment: You probably have not configured your virtual host in your webserver properly. Can you share that configuration (or details on how you've set it up?)

Comment: @AhMing you expect it to generate an issue with the upload, but it will not if you dont hard save the path. can you please test your upload and **if** you encounter an issue with it, post the details of that specific issue. in your WSL installation `"/var/www/html/public"` from within it is equivalent to `"/home/ahming/example-app/public"` from outside of it.

Comment: @AhMing it can also be a simple symlink between the two paths and in your WSL the vhost is declared with the /var path. either way the result of `public_path()` is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since docker environment declare that the storage for the project is under `/var/www/html/`:

`docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
...
services:
    laravel.test:
        ...
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
...
```

Everything need to deal in `/var/www/html`, so when creating symbolic link for public storage, use `./vendor/bin/sail artisan storage:link` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It is because by calling the function `public_path()` you will get the path of that directory. Instead you should get the URL or the domain of that directory; for that it is better to use: `asset()` to get public directory URL

Comment: I faced the problem when writing the code in controller, not in blade, so it is not related to the `asset()`.